# Screen freezes when navigate to component with many views

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am navigating (using react-navigation) from DashboardComponent to CalendarYearView component (in react-native). The screen freezes about 5 seconds when pressing button.

The CalendarYearView component have many sub views (displays a calendar). If I remove the content of render function in CalendarYearView navigation happens instantly.

[video of screen freeze when navigation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1352F6dQehtHQLc5pAlitMlyEJd2oKjrV)

[video when render function is empty](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ndU3oI8YpWV1E3bHI2IGiysRymGV_456)

[App.js where stack navigation is defined](https://pastebin.com/h8W2u3Yy)

[Dashboard.js where screen freezes](https://pastebin.com/udZsAhgu)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: CalendarYearView.SCREEN_KEY });
```

[CalendarYearView.js where navigating to](https://pastebin.com/sjFGgKQ9)

What I have tried:

1. Creating a delay when navigating.
2. Navigating in an async await function.
3. Delete all views in render function. (high speed)
4. Using InteractionManager runAfterInteractions (In this case screen does not freezes but navigation happens after a long time)
5. Next frame (same thing)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is in CalendarYearView.js. There are multiple things that could be improved in that page:

1. When using iterations like `map`, avoid using arrow functions. Because arrow functions are anonymous, they created again and again at each iteration.  If you define the arrow function as a named function, that will be created only once and this really affects performance:

```
monthNum => {
    return (<MonthCalendar
            events={{"2018-11-09": [{ dotColor: 'green'},{dotColor: 'blue'}],"2018-03-11": {}}}month={monthNum}
            year={this.state.year}
            key={monthNum}/>);
    }
```

You should define the following arrow function as a named function in your component:

```
renderMonthCalendar(monthNum) {
    return (<MonthCalendar
            events={{"2018-11-09": [{ dotColor: 'green'},{dotColor: 'blue'}],"2018-03-11": {}}}month={monthNum}
            year={this.state.year}
            key={monthNum}/>);
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
monthNumbers.map(this.renderMonthCalendar);
```

Which will also inject the parameter for you. You can do this to other arrow functions in the page.

2. Avoid using extra components, Views, etc if possible. If you record and inspect the performance tab of the debugger, you will see how an extra component in the page affects the performance. If you hover over the items, it shows how much delay each component causes:

[image]

So if possible, reduce your views and achieve the result with more styling.

3. Use stateless (pure) components. you have several imported components in your page such as MonthCalendar, CalendarAppHeader, YearButton, etc. If these components do not need a state, you can use them just with props.

```
const YearButton = (props) => {
    return(
    );
}
```

You can even convert CalendarAppView into a stateless component. I see only one `setState` in the page. You can control this via props.